# Why are parent's environmentVariables not handed down to subdirectory site?

Tags: .net, .net-core, iis, web-config

I have an IIS 10 server hosting multiple apps, each with multiple environments - QA, PRODUCTION, STAGE, etc. I use environmentVariables in config files to set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable appropriately. In most cases, this works as expected; in one particular case, it does not.

**Site structure:**

All apps are underneath a "default" site, `company_tld`, corresponding to a folder of the same name. That is, App1 is at the physical path \company_tld\App1.

The new apps are part of a server farm; they live at \company_tld\app-farm\server[one|two].

**What I'm doing:**

I set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to STAGE, PRODUCTION, etc., for each app in the appropriate block in \company_tld\web.config. This is ideal, because environment configs persist across deployments.

**The Problem:**

The issue is with the farm servers. So far, the only way I've been able to set this variable is within \company_tld\app-farm\server\one\web.config. I'd prefer to set these at a higher level, outside the deployment folder; but doing so does not seem to pass the variable down to the process.

**What I've tried:**

- Setting the variable through the IIS UI at each level from .\app-farm\server\web.config up to \company-tld\web.config and in the applicationhost file;
- Setting/confirming the UI's directly in the same files by text editor;
- Checking for "stop inheritance" directives at each level (not present).
- "Convert to app" on the .\one directory (no effect versus leaving it as a folder)
- Stopping/starting/recycling app pool after all the above changes (no effect)

Setting the variable in .\one\web.config works perfectly; the same setting 1+ layer(s) "up" does not.
The app starts and content is served, but it does not receive the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable.

What might be the problem here? Is there something I'm missing in configuring an app a couple folders "deep"? Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: You can try to set `Load User Profile` to `true`, so the environment variables are loaded.

Comment: That's for user-level environment variables, no? My apps all run as the same user, and I need to set different values for each.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: I'm trying that. Thanks, @samwu